# Notice: Use of undefined constant FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT

Tags: 7

Attempting to use EFQ for the first time. I'm following a couple walk throughs.

I'm trying to query for the content type banner which has an image field:

```
<?php
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'banner')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->execute();
```

But after doing so the result of this is an error:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT`

What is the cause of this particular error?

Comment: that constant is defined in `field.module` so for some reason in your attempts the Field Module isn't being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that this happens when you're executing this particular function outside of drupal being bootstrapped.

Source: https://drupal.org/node/1286964

Comment: Happening for me even though my code is inside the function